# Add html code to CMS block somehow

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks

I'm extremely new to Magento, I'm using v2, and find the learning curve to be a straight line up. I've created a child theme for Luma and created a page layout called test.xml which I then associated with a page in the CMS.

I'm looking to use the CMS blocks to build layouts, I created a test_cta block in the admin area and then included it in my layout xml file with this code:

```
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="test_cta"> 
        <arguments> 
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">test_cta</argument> 
        </arguments> 
    </block>
```

This worked but how can I make this block reference actual html code? I believe I'm supposed to create a .phtml module of some kind in the /code folder then reference it in my argument shown above?

Comment: Can you include the parent of your `block` please? If we can see that we can give more accurate instructions.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but I suggest you read this article on https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/view-block-layout-template-magento-2.html Hope this helps

Comment: ^^ That does not reference CMS blocks at all

Comment: I realized if I disable the WYSIWYG editor, it allows me to use HTML in the blocks via the CMS. I know I should be using modules instead but it seems like a lot more work to achieve a similar result, seeing as I need to create many blocks/modules.